# chocolate js open image from link attr href

Tags: javascript, chocolat.js

I want to open an image with chocolate js but use the href attribute to pass the url.

Got this from the chocolate [examples](https://chocolat.gitbook.io/chocolat/usage#instanciating-using-javascript-objects):

This works

HTML

```
<a href="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000">click</a>
```

JS

```
const images = [
    { 
    src: 'https://picsum.photos/1000/1000', title: 'image caption a' 
    }
]

const { api } = Chocolat(images, {})

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  api.open();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

instead of the const images I want chocolate to take the var url from my link.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrs05nu2/2/)

Comment: could you explain a bit more ? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: hi. Ive edited my post. I hope its clearer now.

Comment: im sure you are aware that picsum gives you a different image everytime you reload / call it?

Comment: Im using picsum just for an example image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does the trick:

**JS**

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        const images = [
            { src: url },
        ]

        if (window.chocolatInstance) {
            window.chocolatInstance.close();
        }

        window.chocolatInstance = Chocolat(images, {}).api
        chocolatInstance.open();
        
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```